# Change From name when sending emails

Tags: email, exim

I have setup exim4 on Debian 7 to send emails for alerts and stuff on my server to my Gmail account. I edited /etc/email-addresses and added a line:

```
sysadmin: sysadmin@example.com
```

When I receive mail, the from header says "sysadmin sysadmin@example.com". How can I change it to "System Alerts sysadmin@example.com" ?

I've tried editing the logwatch.conf file:

```
MailFrom: "System Alerts <sysadmin@example.com>"
```

but that didn't work.

I've tried editing the /etc/email-addresses file:

```
sysadmin: "System Alerts <sysadmin@example.com"
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: How do you refer to `/etc/email-addresses` in your exim-config?

Comment: I read online to configure /etc/email-addresses to configure the from email so that ISPs/email providers won't reject it.

Comment: Do you use a command line to send your email ? In case yes, which one ?

Comment: @krisFR logwatch is sending the mails

Comment: Is user `sysadmin` actually the Linux user that sends emails ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above modification of `/etc/email-addresses` you have to add a rule in `exim.conf`:

```
begin rewrite

*@myServer.myDomain.net    ${lookup{$1}lsearch{/etc/email-addresses}\
                                        {$value}fail} frFs
```

I hope this helps.